# My batch file skips specific loops

Tags: file, batch-file

My batch file skips specific loops and just does certain loops (it only does the first three loops and ignores the rest).

I tried rewriting the batch file, incorporating the new code into an old existing batch file I wrote, but I can't get it working.

```
echo 1. Login
echo 2. Exit 
echo. 
set /P M = Command : 
IF M == 1 GOTO 1 

:1 

cls 
echo Login 
echo. 
Set Pass1 = MCTh3sn3r 
Set /P Pass = Enter Password : 
IF Pass == %Pass1% GOTO 2

:2 

cls 
echo. 
echo Login Successful GOTO 4

:3 

cls 
echo. 
echo Incorrect Password

:4

echo. 
echo 1. Shutdown (S) 
echo 2. Reboot (R) 
echo 3. Logoff (L) 
echo 4. Task Manager (TM) 
echo 5. Command Prompt (CP) 
echo 6. File Locker (FL) 
echo. Set /P Choice = Command : 
IF Choice == "S" GOTO 5 
IF Choice == "R" GOTO 6 
IF Choice == "L" GOTO 7 
IF Choice == "TM" GOTO 8 
IF Choice == "CP" GOTO 9 
IF Choice == "FL" GOTO 10 

:5

cls 
echo. 
echo System will now shutdown                  
Timeout /t 5
Shutdown /s 
GOTO End 

:6

cls 
echo. 
echo System will now reboot 
timeout /t 5 
Shutdown /r 
GOTO End 

:7

cls 
echo. 
echo System will now logoff 
timeout /t 5 
Logoff 
GOTO End

:8

gpupdate /force 
gpupdate /force 
gpupdate /force 
gpupdate /force 
start taskmgr 
GOTO End

:9 

gpupdate /force 
gpupdate /force 
gpupdate /force 
gpupdate /force 
start cmd 
GOTO End 

:10 
( 

if EXIST "PrivateFolder" goto
11          
if NOT EXIST Locker goto 12 

:13 

echo Are you sure you want to        
lock the folder (Y/N) ? 
set /p Choice = Command : 
IF Choice == "Y" goto 14 
IF Choice == "y" goto 14 
IF Choice == "N" goto 15 
IF Choice == "n" goto 15 
echo Invalid Choice goto 13 

:16 

ren Locker "PrivateFolder" 
attrib +h + s "PrivateFolder" 
echo Folder Locked GOTO End 

:11

echo Enter password to unlock
file :
set /p Pass = Password : 
IF NOT %Pass% == MCTh3sn3r goto
17
attrib -h -s "PrivateFolder" 
ren "PrivateFolder" Locker 
echo File locked successfully. 
GOTO End

:17

echo Invalid password. 
GOTO End

:12 

md Locker 
echo Locker created
successfully. 
GOTO End 

)

:End
Exit
```

Comment: Can you post your code (ideally a minimal runnable example demonstrates the issue)?

Comment: I posted the code so you can have a look. Thanks in advance.

Comment: check your linefeeds. Some of them seem to be random.

Comment: I'm sorry i probably should've stated this earlier, but i'm kind of inexperienced at coding. Its just a hobby of mine and i'm need at it. So can you please elaborate? What exactly do you mean by linefeeds, and which lines in particular do you say are random?

Comment: for example `echo Login Successful GOTO 4`,  `IF NOT %Pass% == MCTh3sn3r goto`(linefeed)`17`

Comment: I can't see exactly what you mean. As far as i can see there isn't anything wrong with my loops or linefeeds. Although you may see problems with the coding that I don't see. My exact problem is that it doesn't matter which option I choose from the menu,  it goes to the shutdown loop, and before I added the exit clause, as soon as I aborted the shutdown, it just skipped to the restart loop.

Comment: @TH3SN3R Well there is a lot of things wrong with your script and I am not even sure where to start.  You should really start with something simple and learn to use the commands one at a time before you try and code something so large.  I will try and break down all your problems one by one.  Some of them should seem pretty obvious if you just look at the code.

Comment: I see exactly zero loops in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well lets start at the TOP.

This set of code has three things wrong with it.

1. Do not leave a space between your variable names and variable assignments.
2. When you need to use  a variable you need to surround it with percent symbols.
3. Your GOTO command will GOTO label 1 regardless of the variable M equaling 1.

.

```
echo 1. Login
echo 2. Exit 
echo. 
set /P M = Command : 
IF M == 1 GOTO 1 

:1
```

This code should really look something like this.

```
echo 1. Login
echo 2. Exit 
echo. 
set /P M=Command : 
IF "%M%"=="1" (
    GOTO 1
) else (
    GOTO END
)

:1
```

You make the same mistakes in the next set of code. Not sure why you chose to use the percent symbols for one variable but not the other. Again, you need to close up the spaces, use percent symbols for all your variables and your GOTO will go to the label 2 regardless so you need some other code to branch to.

```
cls 
echo Login 
echo. 
Set Pass1 = MCTh3sn3r 
Set /P Pass = Enter Password : 
IF Pass == %Pass1% GOTO 2

:2
```

So again, using my best coding practices I would code it like this.

```
:1 


cls 
echo Login 
echo. 
Set Pass1=MCTh3sn3r 
Set /P Pass=Enter Password : 
IF "%Pass%"=="%Pass1%" (
    GOTO 2
) else (
    Echo Wrong Password
    Pause
    GOTO 1
)
```

Just going to keep repeating myself.  Same problems.  Close up the spaces and use percent symbols with your variables.  Might want to throw in a case insensitive check for their choices on this one. Not sure how you thought their answers were ever going to match here.  You have quotes surrounding one side of your comparison but not the other. Not even going to correct this code you should understand by now what you are doing wrong.

```
echo. Set /P Choice = Command : 
IF Choice == "S" GOTO 5 
IF Choice == "R" GOTO 6 
IF Choice == "L" GOTO 7 
IF Choice == "TM" GOTO 8 
IF Choice == "CP" GOTO 9 
IF Choice == "FL" GOTO 10
```

No clue why you are using parentheses here.

```
:10 
(
```

And here.

```
)

:End
Exit
```

This one is dead obvious.  You can't have your label on another line.

```
if EXIST "PrivateFolder" goto
11
```

And here again.  Close up the spaces. Put quotes on both sides of your comparisons. Use percent symbols to reference a variable. And read the HELP for the IF command.  Use the /I option!

```
:13 

echo Are you sure you want to        
lock the folder (Y/N) ? 
set /p Choice = Command : 
IF Choice == "Y" goto 14 
IF Choice == "y" goto 14 
IF Choice == "N" goto 15 
IF Choice == "n" goto 15 
echo Invalid Choice goto 13
```

While we are here I would advise that if you are going to keep using the same variable over and over and over again that you clear out the variable before you ask the question. Make this change above.

```
set "Choice="
set /p Choice=Command :
```

Couple of problems here. The word file: is on its own line. The number 17 is on its own line.  You finally realized that you needed to use percent symbols for you variables but the variable %Pass% is not the same as the variable %Pass %. Close up the spaces and use quotes.

```
echo Enter password to unlock
file :
set /p Pass = Password : 
IF NOT %Pass% == MCTh3sn3r goto
17
```

Comment: I'm giving him the benefit of the doubt on the line labels on separate lines thing and assuming he's coding with word wrap on and the wrapped lines got newline characters added to them. I've seen it happen before.

Comment: Thanks for the effort. I'll try the coding you suggested and hopefully get my program to finally work. And i originally did start with a smaller program, and that actually worked. The login menu and first three options on the menu list are actually remnants from a previous program that i scavenged to use in this one.

Comment: @TH3SN3R not sure how you got that code to work because it would never work in its current form.

Comment: @Squashman Im not sure why it works, but it does. I can send you the original code and you can see for yourself.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I finally got the code working perfectly. I compiled it and its running smoothly now. Thanks again